# alignment of authors in ieee journal paper

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style, author, journal, ieeeaccess

I have added authors in ieee journal paper but it is lining up authors I want to add 2 or 3 authors in the same line
Here is my code

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{name} \\
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{department} \\
\textit{ university }\\
address\\
email}


\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{name} \\
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{department} \\
\textit{ university }\\
address\\
email}


\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{name} \\
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{department} \\
\textit{ university }\\
address\\
email}

\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{name} \\
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{department} \\
\textit{ university }\\
address\\
email}

\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{name} \\
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{department} \\
\textit{ university }\\
address\\
email}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to IEEEtran [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) Section IV.B, `\IEEEauthorblockN` and `\IEEEauthorblockA` only work properly in *conference* mode. If you are submitting to IEEE journals, it is better to follow their style instructions and place additional information with `\thanks` macro.